# How to in .Net core domain model replace validation of primitive types with value objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design

.Net Core 3

By [this](https://paulovich.net/designing-testing-input-validation-in-dotnet-core-the-clean-architecture-way/) and [this](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/combining-asp-net-core-attributes-with-value-objects/) examples I try create validation of domain model with value objects.
But I get error.

```
// Value object TitleValue
 public class TitleValue : ValueObject
    {

        public string Value { get; }

        public TitleValue()
        {
        }

        public TitleValue(string value)
        {
            Value = value;
            Create(value);
        }

        public static Result<TitleValue> Create(string input)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
                return Result.Fail<TitleValue>(Errors.General.ValueIsRequired().Serialize());

            string title = input.Trim();

            if (title.Length > 2)
                return Result.Fail<TitleValue>(Errors.General.ValueIsTooLong().Serialize());



            return Result.Ok(new TitleValue(title));
        }


        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents()
        {
            yield return Value;
        }
    }
```

```
// Domain model 
 public class Navigation
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public TitleValue Title { get; set; } // there is problem
        public string Slug { get; set; }
        public byte IsCategory { get; set; }
        public int Sort { get; set; }
        public int Parent { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EdRoleNavigation> RoleNavigations { get; set; }
    }
```

I get error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'TitleValue' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateNonNullPrimaryKeys(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger logger)

.Net core thinks, that  the TitleValue is an entity.

How I can fix this error, and get a nice validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The NotMapped attribute is used to specify that an entity or property is not to be mapped to a table or column in the database.](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/notmapped-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell EF that TitleValue is a Value Object.

On `OnModelCreating`:

```
    builder.Entity<Navigation>().OwnsOne(n => n.TitleValue, n => n.Property(p => p.Value).HasColumnName("Title"));
```

or in `IEntityTypeConfiguration.Configure`:

```
    builder.OwnsOne(n => n.TitleValue, n => n.Property(p => p.Value).HasColumnName("Title"));
```

Where `OwnsOne` sets `TitleValue` as Value Object (problem solved).

The second expression tells EF you want the database column named "Title" instead of the default "Title_Value".